# DatePicker MUI mask issue

Tags: reactjs, web, material-ui, datepicker, vite

I'm having problems creating a mask, only the second condition is met, the first one, even isMonth returning true is not fulfilled. Follow the code:

```
<DatePicker
      inputFormat={AgregacaoShortDateFormat[agregacao.value]}
      mask={isMonth ? "__/____" : "__/__/____"}
      views={isMonth ? ["month", "year"] : ["day", "month", "year"]}
      openTo={isMonth ? "month" : "day"}
      value={data}
      onChange={(value: DateTime | null): void => setValue("data", (isMonth ? value?.startOfMonth() : value) ?? DateTime.now())}
      disabled={realTime}
/>
```

Comment: Well eeehm..  The masks are the same for both true and false in your example..

Comment: I made the correction, I made the mistake by sending the question to the Stack

Comment: So..  You still have the issue?
The MUI datePicker doesnt seem to have a mask prioperty at all.